Generate fake data with Bogus Library for making unit tests
For creating fake data I've been using Bogus package together with Theory class for my unit tests. But as expected I have some classes I need fake data of them such as entities and dtos.
Here is my entity user
    public sealed class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; } = null!;
    }

Here are my dtos.
public sealed record CreateUserRequest(
    [Required, StringLength(maximumLength:50)]
    string FirstName,

    [Required, StringLength(maximumLength:70)]
    string LastName,

    [Required, StringLength(maximumLength:25)]
    string UserName,

    [Required, StringLength(maximumLength:70), DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), EmailAddress]
    string Email,

    [Required, MinLength(5), DataType(DataType.Password)]
    string Password,

    [Required, Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    int RoleId
    );


public sealed record UserResponse(
    Guid Id,
    string Name,
    string LastName,
    string Email
    );

So, I created this static class:
internal static class UserTestDataFactory
{
    public static List<User> CreateManyUsers(int count)
    {
        Faker<User> userFaker = new Faker<User>()
            .RuleFor(u => u.FirstName, f => f.Name.FirstName())
            .RuleFor(u => u.LastName, f => f.Name.LastName())
            .RuleFor(u => u.Email, f => f.Internet.Email())
            .RuleFor(u => u.Password, f => f.Internet.Password())
            .RuleFor(u => u.Username, f => f.Internet.UserName())
            .RuleFor(u => u.IsActive, f => f.Random.Bool());
        return userFaker.Generate(count);
    }
    public static List<CreateUserRequest> CreateManyUserRequests(int count)
    {
        Faker<CreateUserRequest> faker = new Faker<CreateUserRequest>()
            .CustomInstantiator(f =>
                new CreateUserRequest(
                    f.Name.FirstName(),
                    f.Name.LastName(),
                    f.Internet.UserName(),
                    f.Internet.Email(),
                    f.Internet.Password(),
                    f.Random.Number(1, 7)));
        return faker.Generate(count);
    }
    public static User CreateSingleUser()
    {
        return CreateManyUsers(1).First();
    }

    public static CreateUserRequest CreateSingleUserRequest()
    {
        return CreateManyUserRequests(1).First();
    }
    public static List<UserResponse> CreateManyUserResponses(int count)
    {
        var fakerUserResponse = new Faker<UserResponse>()
            .CustomInstantiator(f =>
                new UserResponse(
                    Guid.NewGuid(),
                    f.Name.FirstName(),
                    f.Internet.Email(),
                    f.Name.LastName()));
        return fakerUserResponse.Generate(count, nameof(fakerUserResponse));
    }
}

So far, I don't see anything wrong with it. But what if I end up having many more classes? Should I continue using the same approach or change to another?
Here are my test data for my unit test.
public class CreateUserValidTestData : TheoryData<CreateUserRequest>
{
    public CreateUserValidTestData()
    {
        Add(UserTestDataFactory.CreateSingleUserRequest());
        Add(UserTestDataFactory.CreateSingleUserRequest());
        Add(UserTestDataFactory.CreateSingleUserRequest());
    }

}

public class UserListValidTestData : TheoryData<List<User>>
{
    public UserListValidTestData()
    {
        /*var testData = new TestDataFactory<UserData, User>().Create();
        Add(testData.Multiple(6));
        Add(testData.Multiple(1));
        Add(testData.Multiple(4));
        Add(testData.Multiple(10));*/
        Add(UserTestDataFactory.CreateManyUsers(2));
        Add(UserTestDataFactory.CreateManyUsers(5));
        Add(UserTestDataFactory.CreateManyUsers(6));
    }
}

Here I am using UserListValidTestData and CreateUserValidTestData classes
public class UserServiceTest
{
    [Theory, ClassData(typeof(UserListValidTestData))]
    public async Task GetAllAsync_Should_ReturnUserList_WhenUsersExist(IReadOnlyList<User> usersExpected)
    {
        // Arrange
        Mock<IUserRepository> mockUserRepository = new();

        mockUserRepository
            .Setup(repository => repository.GetAllAsync())
            .ReturnsAsync(usersExpected)
            .Verifiable(Times.Once());
        UserService userService = new(mockUserRepository.Object, default!, default!);

        // Act
        var result = await userService.GetAllAsync();

        // Assert
        mockUserRepository.Verify();
        result.IsSuccess
            .Should()
            .BeTrue();
        result.Value
            .Should()
            .BeAssignableTo<IReadOnlyList<UserResponse>>();
        result.Value
            .Should()
            .NotBeEmpty()
            .And
            .HaveSameCount(usersExpected);
    }

    [Theory, ClassData(typeof(CreateUserValidTestData))]
    public async Task CreateAsync_Should_ReturnId_WhenUserDoesNotExist(
        CreateUserRequest request)
    {
        // Arrange
        User expected = new()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            FirstName = request.FirstName,
            LastName = request.LastName,
            Username = request.UserName,
            Email = request.Email,
            RoleId = request.RoleId,
            IsActive = true
        };

        Mock<IUserRepository> mockUserRepository = new();
        Mock<IUnitOfWork> mockUnitOfWork = new();
        Mock<IPasswordHasher<User>> mockPasswordHasher = new();

        mockPasswordHasher.Setup(provider => provider.HashPassword(It.IsAny<User>(), request.Password))
            .Returns(It.IsAny<string>())
            .Verifiable(Times.Once());

        mockUserRepository
            .Setup(repo => repo.ExistAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(false)
            .Verifiable(Times.Once());

        mockUserRepository
            .Setup(repo => repo.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<User>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(expected)
            .Verifiable(Times.Once());

        mockUnitOfWork
            .Setup(unitOfWork => unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(default))
            .ReturnsAsync(1) // Simulate a successfull save operation affecting 1 row
            .Verifiable(Times.Once());

        UserService userService = new(
            mockUserRepository.Object,
            mockUnitOfWork.Object,
            mockPasswordHasher.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await userService.CreateAsync(request);

        // Assert
        mockUserRepository.Verify();
        mockUnitOfWork.Verify();
        mockPasswordHasher.Verify();
        result.IsSuccess
            .Should()
            .BeTrue();
        result.Error
            .Should()
            .Be(Error.None);
        result.Value
            .Should()
            .NotBeEmpty()
            .And
            .Be(expected.Id);
    }

Pd: I've recently started with unit testing.
Thoughts or advice is gratefully received...

I don't like writing tons of code to simply populate some class with dummy data. My default go-to is NSubstitute, AutoFixture and FluentAssertions. 1 line, using AutoFixture replaces a whole data setup. There is pros and cons but unless I have to create a manual mock, I just don't like wasting time on manually writing mocks which I then also have to keep maintaining.
